# Request is not defined after installing request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

I'm creating a script which is going to receive a data from API every 24 hours in specific time.
I'm using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) package
After I trying to see the script in terminal or in chrome console log. I receive an error that request is not defined.

I installed RequireJS already, but the error still appears.
I was trying the example from node-schedule documentation itself, also receiving the same error in terminal.
Where is my mistake and how I can fix it?

Code below:

```
var schedule = require("node-schedule");

var j = schedule.scheduleJob("*/55 20 * * *", function() {
    request(
            "GET",
            "http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY"
        )
        .then((r1) => {
            var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

            var BTCdata = x1.data.find((d) => d.symbol === "BTC").quote.USD
                .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

            console.log(BTCdata);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

function request(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = resolve;
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: You havn't required the `request` module in your file like you have for `node-schedule`

Comment: @tbking I edited the code. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please paste error stack for better understanding of the issue